# Umbraco Templates Modifying View Path

Tags: c#, .net, razor, .net-6.0, umbraco

I am working on an Umbraco project with some templates that reference cshtml files in a C# .NET 6 Web Project Views folder like so:

[image]

Those views are referenced by the Umbraco UI through templates like such:

[image]

All these templates have a path referencing that same Views folder mentioned above here:

[image]

I now have a requirement to reference another set of views in a separate Razor class library  from the same Umbraco database. So the question is can I change that /Views/AccordionPage.cshtml path above for a subset of the templates to instead refer to a different set of views e.g. ../RazorProject/Views/AccordionPage.cshtml?